# Replace certain elements of matrix with NaN (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a vector, A.

```
A=[3,4,5,2,2,4;2,3,4,5,3,4;2,4,3,2,3,1;1,2,3,2,3,4]
```

Some of the records in A must be replaced by NaN values, as they are inaccurate. 
I have created vector rowid, which records the last value that must be kept after which the existing values must be swapped to NaN.

```
rowid=[4,5,4,3]
```

So the vector I wish to create, B, would look as follows:

```
B=[3,4,5,2,NaN,NaN;2,3,4,5,3,NaN;2,4,3,2,NaN,NaN;1,2,3,NaN,NaN,NaN]
```

I am at a loss as to how to do this. I have tried to use

```
A(:,rowid:end)
```

to start selecting out the data from vector A. I am expecting to be able to use sub2ind or some sort of idx to do this, possibly an if loop, but I don't know where to start and cannot find an appropriate similar question to base my thoughts on!

I would very much appreciate any tips/pointers, many thanks

Comment: seems like you have two separate questions here, might be better to split them into different posts..

Comment: Indeed, I would remove the paragraph about the 10% and ask that in a separate question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not yet an expert of matlab, I would stick to simple for-loops for now:

```
B = A;
for i=1:length(rowid)
    B(i, rowid(i)+1:end) = NaN;
end
```

It is always a sport to write this as a one-liner (see Mohsen's answer), but in many cases an explicit for-loop is much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

A compact one is:

```
B = A;
B(bsxfun(@lt, rowid.', 1:size(A,2)))=NaN;
```

Comment: +1 but surely it should be `B(bsxfun(@lt, rowid.', 1:size(A,2)))=NaN;`